# NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for UrlHandlingStrategy

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-router, circular-dependency

In my application, after upgrading to angular 14, I am facing the following error. I use lazy loading and have properly configured RouterModule for Root and child and have imported it in app.module.ts. Also, along with this facing a circular dependency error for Router. Not sure how to debug this further to resolve the error. Thank you for your guidance in advance!

```
app err NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for UrlHandlingStrategy!
at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:)
at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:)
at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:)
at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:)
at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:)
at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:)
at inject (core.mjs:)
at Object.setupRouter [as useFactory] (router.mjs:)
at Object.factory (core.mjs:)
at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:)
```

Comment: Please provide more details, if possible a stackblitz with the minimal problem reproduction!

Comment: Try the following article: https://blog.nrwl.io/upgrading-angular-applications-managing-routers-and-url-ca5588290aaa, your error seems to imply that you never actually defined the handling strategy in your providers (in the ng module lvl) nor did you define a class that would implement it

Comment: Hi @SomeStudent, thanks. Yes, I do not have a handling strategy in the provider. I'm not sure, but is Handling Strategy a mandatory configuration to provide?

Comment: That I am not sure. I assume this is angular JS to modern angular? If so then it might be. I don’t recall having to use one locally in my projects, however they are the latest version of angular

Comment: Hi @SomeStudent, no, actually I am not migrating Angular JS to Angular. Only change I made was from Angular 12 version to 14, then started facing these error on building the app. I am also confused as to why these errors.

Comment: Can't say I am sure then, no where in my work project do I define that handler. Have you tried following the upgrade steps here? https://update.angular.io/?v=12.0-13.0 try going 12 -> 13 -> 14

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same issue, apparently, the issue was because of the mismatch between the Angular versions, make sure your all Angular packages are in the same version.